# Is there any way to render a perfect curve just like pointclouds in blender?

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes, point-clouds

When we use the 'curve to mesh' node in geometry nodes, sometimes we cannot get an ideal results because mesh overlap frequently happens and leads to bad shading on surface, just like this figure:
[image: Result of 'curve to mesh' node]

[image: Mesh render]

So I tried to transform the curve into dense pointclouds to get "perfect curve". I did get a much better shading on curve surface (shown below), but this idea was too primitive that cost too much computer performance.

[image: Pointcloud render 1]

[image: Pointcloud render 2 For a better understanding]

I can't help think about that, is there a way to render a curve just like the way we render pointclouds in blender? Since point cloud can be rendered into perfect spheres, there should be a similar way for curve.

Answer (score 0):

Yes (but not cyclic).
You use the new hair system. what you do is wrap the curves you want to render in a hair object and set the radius.